# XML dateTime unmarshalling to NULL

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, jaxb, annotations

I have the following xml element:

```
    <SchedDate>
        <dateTime>2014-07-09T00:00:00-05:00</dateTime>
    </SchedDate>
```

And I have the following annotation in my code:

```
     /**
     * @return the schedDate
     */
    @XmlElement(name = "SchedDate")
    public Date getSchedDate() {
        return schedDate;
    }
```

When I unmarshall this xml the schedDate attribute is NULL. All other fields from the xml are unmarshalled properly.

Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML document expects the date to be an element called `dateTime`, but you have mapped it to an element called `SchedDate` with the `@XmlElement` annotation.

**Your XML Document Has**

```
<dateTime>2014-07-09T00:00:00-05:00</dateTime>
```

**You Have Mapped To**

```
<SchedDate>2014-07-09T00:00:00-05:00</SchedDate>
```

Comment: I don't have a space in mine. It's '2014-07-09T00:00:00-05:00'

Comment: great, I will try "SchedDate/dateTime" for my mapping!

Comment: @75inchpianist - Using standard JAXB APIs you won't be able to map directly to `SchedDate/dateTime`, although you can use an `XmlAdapter` to handle this.  We do have an `@XmlPath` extension in EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy) that allows you to do this:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html

Comment: hmm used "@XmlPath("SchedDate/dateTime")" and its still returning null.

Comment: @75inchpianist - You will need to specify `@XmlPath("SchedDate/dateTime/text()")`.  You will also need to be sure that you have correctly specified MOXy as your JAXB provider:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html